# Swift Alamofire patch multiform

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to upload a picture with some data to a rest api that I have and I have been able to get it to work with a post request but when using put/patch request no data is being sent to the server. Currently this endpoint updated the record of the user.

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if let name = user.name.data(using: .utf8){
            multipartFormData.append(name, withName: "name")
        }
        if let email = user.name.data(using: .utf8){
            multipartFormData.append(email, withName: "email")
        }

        if let cover = cover {
            multipartFormData.append(cover.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6)!, withName: "cover", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }
    }, to: "https://test.com/api/v1/users/\(id)", method: .patch, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
    }
```

when checking the on the api end nothing is in the request when it is being sent to attempts the call. and the data is there I am able to get data to print out in swift.

When I look at the backend and log out the request there are no request attributes being sent to the server even though I added attributes in the call using Alamofire multipartFormData.append.

Comment: You are using if/let before appending to the formdata, are you sure that the values are not `nil`? Because, if they are all your `append` calls are skipped and you will send no body data.

Comment: yes I checked the values and the are not nil. I have it were name and email are never nil. I just needed to safely unwrap them due to the data method had to be unwrapped